# How to determine if a translatable field has translation enabled?

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

How can I figure out if a translation for a translatable field has been enabled?

I don't mean if a field is translatable in general. e.g.:

```
$entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
$bundle = $entity->bundle();
$fields = $this->entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle);
foreach($fields as $field){
  if($field->isTranslatable()){
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Could the langcode be a reliable information? If it is 'und' e.g.:

```
if($entity->get('name')->getLangcode() != 'und'){
  // The field translation is enabled:
}
```

Comment: You say what you don't mean, but you could explain what you mean or what you want to achieve.

Comment: As stated in the title I want to know if the field has translation enabled aka if I edit the entity in different languages I will have different values and not "(all languages)" indicated next to the label. I want to achieve a generic solution for any entity adding translations automatically but only for fields that are configured for multilanguage. Therefore I need to figure out for a given entity which fields are translation enabled for operating only on those.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the translation is enabled on a field:

```
if ($entity->get('name')->getFieldDefinition()->isTranslatable()) {
  // The field translation is enabled:
}
```

which is by the way the same field definition you get in your code example, only here it is retrieved from the field directly. There is no difference between *translatable* and *translation enabled* as long as the entity is translatable.

Comment: Are you sure? My debugging shows that this is not the case. I get the same FieldDefinition from the field then if I load it through the entityFieldManager. The FieldDefinition is not altered by the field configuration in the content language configuration. (/admin/config/regional/content-language) there you can check if a field is translatable on a per field bases. This is independent of the configuration that an entity is translatable.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If I change a field in /admin/config/regional/content-language and export the config before and after and make a diff I can see that only the `translatable` property of the bundle field definition does change. If it is a base field, then this information is stored in a bundle specific base field override.